# error in command "installed.packages" in R language

Tags: r, package

This command: `installed.packages(c("ggplot2","swirl","lattice","car","fimport","tseries"))`
generates the error

> *"Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests  Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type  Archs
>   MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built"*

command: installed.packages(c("ggplot2")) same mistake
command: install.packages("devtools")  execution completes successfully

Environment
Windows 10
RStudio: Version 1.2.5042
version R 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)

What's error?

Comment: there is a difference between `install.packages` and `installed.packages` I think you should switch your functions to `install.packages`. R's auto complete might make it go to install`ed` and not install.

Comment: are you trying to install the packages?

Comment: Thanks. it is a my mistake, i wrote installed

Answer (score 1):

use `install.packages('dplry')` as answered by @Mike